# Can wh- pronouns function as objects in a wh- clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I've recently become interested in relative pronouns and wh- clauses. During my research, I found out about using [relative pronouns as objects](https://parentingpatch.com/using-relative-pronoun-direct-objects/). For example ('that' is an object of 'my father'):

> 'This is the house that my father built.'

This made me curious about whether wh- clauses also function in the same way. I know that they can be referred to as [embedded questions](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/embedded-questions.html), so I realise that there is an immediate difference. I have also noted that wh- pronouns don't function in the same way as relative pronouns, as they are lacking an antecedent.

However, there are overlaps between them, which can be seen in the case of [nominal relative clauses](https://www.thoughtco.com/free-nominal-relative-clause-1690808). My understanding is that nominal relatives shorten from traditional relative clauses to form something resembling a wh- clause. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

This brings me to the point of my question: can wh- pronouns be objects in a wh- clause? In this example, this is clearly not possible; there is no other pronoun after 'what' to make it so.

> 'I don't know what made him do it.'

In the second example, however, 'what' is immediately followed by 'force.' Using the logic applied with relative pronouns, I would say that this makes 'what' an object. But I acknowledge that the link is strenuous at best.

> 'I don't know what force possessed him to do it.'

Please could someone elaborate on the differences or confirm if I'm correct about this?

Comment: *What* as an **object** (functions like a noun):  _I don't know **what** he ate. He ate **that**._  ... *What* as a **modifier** (functions like an adjective):  _I don't know **what** food he ate. He ate **that** food._  ... *What* as a subject (functions like a noun): _I don't know **what** made him eat. **Something** made him eat._

Comment: No. _That_ is not the object of _my_. It's the object of _built_. Verbs have objects; possessive pronouns don't have objects. That's as far as I got in reading the question.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you for the correction. For clarity, I meant to write 'my father,' as 'my' is simply a possessive determiner. However, as you have explained, that would be incorrect too. I learned to spot objects using other nouns, which is how the confusion has come about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

> I don't know ***what*** made him do it.

***what*** is a *relative pronoun* heading the clause which functions as the *object* for the verb *know*. Within the object wh-clause, *what* is the subject of the verb *made*.

In

> I don't know ***what** force* possessed him to do it.

*what force possessed him to do it* is again the object of *know*, but this time, within the wh-clause, ***what*** is used as the determiner of the noun ***force***. The subject of the verb *possessed* is *force*, and *what* is modifying it.

So in your two sentences, ***what*** is part of an object clause, but not an object in itself.

However, if you said:

> I don't know ***what*** he thought of me.

Within the object wh- clause, ***what*** would be the object of the verb *thought*. So to answer your question,

> can wh- pronouns be objects in a wh- clause?

Yes, they can.  [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-interrogative-pronouns-what-who) asserts this too:

> We can use ***who***, ***whose***, ***which*** and ***what*** both as subject and object.

The examples it gives are direct questions, but if you transform them into indirect ones, the function of these pronouns does not change. Consider:

> What did you buy? (Cambridge example of *what* used as an object)

If you put *I don't know* before you get:

> I don't know ***what*** you bought.

Here the situation is as I have explained for *I don't know what he thought of me.*